# Probability that a random selection of points in $[0,1]^2$ have positive consecutive slopes

Tags: probability

This basically evolved from a showerthought I had and was wondering if someone could make some helpful comments on where I am going wrong.

Suppose we sample some points $x_1,\ldots, x_k \in [0,1]^2$ and we investigate the chance that the consecutive line segments between $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ all have positive slope, we denote this event $U_k$. Now I was thinking the following (which turns out to be wrong).

The chance that $x_1,\ldots, x_{k-1}$ are all contained in a small rectangle $[0,a]\times [0,b]$ is $(ab)^{-k+1}$, and the chance that the last one is contained in the rectangle $[a,1]\times [b,1]$ is $ ((1-a)(1-b))^{-1} $. The chance that the first $k-1$ random points have positive consecutive slopes is $\Pr(U_{k-1})$ because the domain is just a scaling of $[0,1]^2$.

So I figured, that
\begin{equation}
\Pr(U_k) = \int\limits_{0}^1\int\limits_{0}^1  \frac{\Pr(U_{k-1})}{(xy)^{k-1}} \frac{dxdy}{(1-x)(1-y)}.
\end{equation}
This is at least undercounting in the sense that I consider now only the event that the $x_k$ random variable turns out to be in the top right corner, which has (I guess) a chance of $k^{-1}$. So I might need to multiply by some factor, but lets leave that for now.

Now, $\Pr(U_1) = 1$ and so this formula tells me that
\begin{equation}
\Pr(U_k) = \int\limits_{0}^1\int\limits_{0}^1  \frac{1}{xy} \frac{dxdy}{(1-x)(1-y)},
\end{equation}
but this expression is $0$ while it should intuitively be $\frac{1}{2}$, as the line segments is *non flat* almost surely.

So, who can shed some insight on this, sorry if my terminology is slightly off, as I said this has not been a rigorous investigation by me but more a fun excursion into new strange parts of mathematics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear to me what your "consecutive" means here: consecutive in the order drawn or numerically consecutive.  In either case, though, the numerical ordering of the $y_i$ corresponding to the "consecutive" $x_i$ induces a uniformly distributed permutation, and so  $P(U_k)=1/k!$.

Comment: Ah sorry yeah that was unclear, I mean consecutive in the left to right sense, so disregarding the ordering of the $x_i$. I understand your answer, Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Actually in the case of 'consecutive in the order drawn' (which I take to mean that the $x$-coordinates are not necessarily increasing as you go from one point to the next), the probability of all slopes positive seems to be greater than $\frac{1}{n!}$.  Having said that, the case of the order of points being taken in increasing $x$-coordinate, which seems to be the case of interest to OP, the answer $\frac{1}{n!}$ is correct.

Comment: In the "consecutive in the order drawn" case this appears to reduce to determining the probability that two randomly selected permutations of $[n]$ have the same descent set.  See for example https://oeis.org/A060350.